# Open Source SCORM player

Tags: scorm1.2

I have a web Application running in PHP and Apache, I now have a requirement to run the SCORM packages within this application.The SCORM content will be accessed from the remote server.I am looking for a free SCORM player that can access this content and display it to the users. I am working with SCORM for the first time and surfed a lot online but couldn't find anything suitable. Can you please provide some help?

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight testing tool [TinyLMS](http://www.randelshofer.ch/tinylms/index.html) is worth a shot.

You could also set up a local copy of an open source LMS like [Moodle](https://moodle.org/).

Answer (score 0):

One option you may want to check out is SCORM Cloud. It's a hosted service that lets you host, deliver and track your SCORM packages. There is an API with a PHP library that you could use to integrate it with your application. There is a free trial if you want to try it out, but the service beyond that is not free.

Here is more information http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/scorm-cloud-api/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Since the application built in PHP is for internal use only within the organization, I am looking for some free solution. Would be helpful if some help can be provided